# Help with MCI video window

Tags: c#

I'm programming a multimedia player in c#, and I use a picturebox to handle the video window. I want the video will be play in fullscreen when I double-click on the video window but I can't find any way to do that. Can anyone help me? Please! (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently there is no built-in way to do it.

try [here](http://www.techtalkz.com/c-c-sharp/125478-display-jpg-full-screen-mode.html) for some instructions

Answer (score 0):

You can play video in an already-created window using the following MCI strings:

```
open file.mpg type MPEGVideo Alias XXXX
window XXXX handle 1234
put XXXX destination
play XXXX
```

Once the video is playing in the window you can move and resize the window at will. I'm not sure if you can get away with actually maximising the window: if not then you can simulate this by resizing the window to fit the screen.